# Form Validation to Allow 6 or 9 numbers Only?

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation, preg-match

I have a form with a field that accepts numbers only for an access code. Access codes are either 6 or 9 numbers. Currently I'm validating the field with

```
elseif (( ! is_numeric($values['access'])) || ! preg_match('/[0-9]{6,9}$/', $values['access']))
```

which allows between 6 and 9 numbers. How can I allow only 6 or 9 numbers?

I'm guess it's something like

```
elseif (( ! is_numeric($values['access'])) || ! preg_match('/[0-9]{6}[0-9]{9}$/', $values['access']))
```

But we all know that wont work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `^[0-9]{6}$|^[0-9]{9}$`?

Comment: `strlen` in enough

Comment: When referring to the characters 0-9 you should use the term "digits" instead of "numbers", as in some cases a string of digits may be construed to represent a single "number".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(a|b)` will match either a or b. So!

```
^(\d{6}|\d{9})$
```

Will match either 6 numerals, or 9 numerals.

Which you can put to the test here https://regex101.com/r/Chx10H/1/

Comment: Though I prefer your answer, `^(?!\d{7,8}$)\d{6,9}$` also works. `(?!\d{7,8}$)` is a *negative lookahead* that prevents strings of length 7 or 8 from matching.

Answer (score 1):

More efficient way, it takes 27 steps (accepted answer 36 steps):

```
  ^\d{6}(?:\d{3})?$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Chx10H/2)